# Read binary file to struct array pointer

Tags: arrays, c, binaryfiles

I have written a struct array to a binary file using this function:

```
int write_binary(const char* filename, const Product* shop)
{
    FILE* OUT;
    int jees = 0;
    int i = 0;

    OUT = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (!OUT) {
        return 1;
    }

    while (jees == 0)
    {
//the last element of the struct array has '\0' as the first char of its name
        if (shop[i].name[0] == '\0')
        {
        jees = 1;
        }
        fwrite(&shop[i], sizeof (Product), 1, OUT) ;
        i++;  
    }
    
    fclose(OUT);

    return 0;
}
```

Now I want to read it back into a struct array pointer. I have tried:

```
Product* read_binary(const char* filename)
{
    FILE* IN = fopen(filename,"rb");
    Product *shop;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    fread(&shop[i], sizeof(Product), 1, IN);
    }
    fclose(IN);

    return shop;
}
```

But this way doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to find out the how many structs are in the binary data?

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to work" mean?  And if you knew the size of the file, would that be enough to deduce the number of structs?

Comment: “doesn't seem to work” is not a problem description. State the observed behavior. State the expected behavior. Edit the question to provide a [mre]. That said, the write function writes until a name is empty (first character is zero). So the read function could read until a name is empty.

Comment: Cqn you provide the struct definition? is the array static in the struct or a pointer to an array stored elsewhere?

Comment: `*shop` is uninitialized - you need to allocate memory for it before reading.

Comment: Your `read_binary` uses pointer `shop` while its value is indeterminate.  You need to assign a valid `Product *` value to it, one pointing to enough memory to accommodate 10 `Product`s.

Comment: By the way, do not write `sizeof (type)`, as in `sizeof (Product)`. It is too easy to make a mistake this way, such as leaving the type unchanged when editing the object being written to something else or vice-versa or other issues. Instead, write `sizeof foo`, where `foo` is the thing you want the size of, such as `fread(&shop[i], sizeof shop[i], 1, IN);`.

Answer (score 3):

`Product *shop;`
Here you are declaring a pointer, but you are not allocating memory for it. You should allocate with `malloc()` or do some static allocation.

To know the number of structs in the file, I'd seek to the end of it, count the bytes and divide by the size of the struct.

Answer (score 0):

A side note: you don't need the `jees` variable. Just test the breaking condition *after* writing and break the loop explicitly:

```
    for (i = 0; ; i++)
    {
        fwrite(&shop[i], sizeof (Product), 1, OUT);

        if (shop[i].name[0] == '\0')
            break;
    }
```